# How to get user details (job, title, department, location etc) using outlook EWS using his AD login ID

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I need to get certain details for a user by his AD login ID.

Remember I just don't want to look into that user's contacts only. I want to look in global list and find the details (Similar details is shown when you double click the name of the person in the email message from, to, cc )

I found lot of links out there but they don't show any example for global search of user.

I tried to do something similar shown in this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220498(v=exchg.80).aspx

however it just within my own contacts.

Can anybody show a simple example or link for the same?

Answer (score 2):

I found that ResolveName method does the trick. I can query by user's full name. I am just posting a method. I assume 'service' is already instantiated using proper domain/url/credentials

```
 public Contact GetContactInfo(string sFullName)
    {
        Contact contact = null;
        try
        {
            NameResolutionCollection allContacts = service.ResolveName(sFullName, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true);

            if (allContacts.Any())
            {
                contact = allContacts[0].Contact;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.Error("Error in GetContactInfo(): ", ex);
            //throw;
        }


        return contact;




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ResolveName method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.resolvename%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

You can search the contacts folder and/or global address list with it. Make sure you set the boolean value to return the Contact with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for user's details and **GetPersona** is the operation.
Sharing with the concern that it may help others who are digging google & Microsoft to get user's information.

[GetPersona operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191408%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

The **GetPersona** operation returns a set of properties that are associated with a persona.